# Dialog in WPF dissapears when clicking on application icon in taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dialog

I have a WPF application where i show a dialog with

```
  nrDialog.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
  bool? dialogResult = nrDialog.ShowDialog();
```

The dialog is a simple Window object with properties

```
Title="NewReportDialog" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize">
```

The windows works as normal modal dialog and locks mainwindow as it should , but when i click on the application icon on the taskbar, Windows 7, the modal dialog goes out of focus and the only way to get the dialog back in to focus is to use ALT-Tab

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: You mean it goes behind the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set the [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) of the dialog Window to be the main application window. This should solve the issue.

Probably something like:

```
nrDialog.Owner = this;
```

Where *this* is the main window instance. You can replace it with something more relevant to your case.

You can get the main application window using: Application.Current.MainWindow

Comment: Thanks, as im calling showdialog from controller this in my case is Application.Current.MainWindow